# 木木 is there anything linked to a Chinese superstition with this double character?

Tags: translation

Is there anything linked to a Chineses superstition with this double
character?

I am "going to" start learning Chinese because I met a lady etc.
Her Chat has 木木 (may) her American name. I asked about it - 
we mostly correspond through google translate.
She said it's 'different'. Then she said it has superstition, and
she doesn't know how to explain it to me.

I have googled and googled; all I get trees and wood.

So I ask Stack Exchange... is there anything linked to a Chineses superstition with this double character?

Comment: "Her Chat has 木木 (may) her American name" Do you mean that her name is 林 or she mentioned about it in chat or she has an american name about it?

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear. All I can think of is Lincoln, (as in Abraham Lincoln, the president) is transliterated as 林肯, who was assasinated. Other than that, I am not aware of any "superstition" attached to the word 林 per se.

Comment: Perhaps "superstition" is too strong a word in this context. Check out this Thread for some insight into the subject. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35844/how-can-i-make-a-two-character-chinese-girls-name-perhaps-using-%e9%9d%99/35856#35856

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your thoughts. 
Well turns out it wasn't some Chinese superstition; it was sort of her own; this is how she explained it finally:
"There is a superstition in China. People want to know his own destiny and what his life is. For example, some are fire, some are water, and some are wood. This is based on his birth date. People who look at their destiny are called  Fortune teller, the fortune teller said that my life is short of wood, so I thought of a name called wood wood, this is superstition This is a kind of superstition in China, similar to a belief In other words, my name is Mumu, which is helpful for my good luck

Comment: 生辰八字 is what this is called.

Comment: That makes sense now. There are many people named 鑫，森，淼，焱，垚 because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the *"five elements"（五行）*.

*"Five elements"* are Metal（金）, Wood（木）, Water（水）, Fire（火） and soil（土）。

The five elements are an important part of Chinese traditional culture.

> 中国古代思想家试图用这五种物质来说明万物的起源。它们是道教教义理论的重要内容。中医用五行来说明生理病理上的种种现象。迷信的人用五行相生相克来推算人的命运。
>
> Ancient Chinese thinkers tried to use these five substances to explain the origin of everything. They are an important part of Taoist doctrine. Five elements of traditional Chinese medicine to explain various phenomena in physiology and pathology. Superstitious people use five elements to calculate the fate of each other.
> -《现代汉语词典》*"Modern Chinese Dictionary"*

Here is a sentence in great writer Lu Xun（鲁迅）'s article *"Motherland"*（《故乡》）

> ... Born in a leap month（闰rùn月）, lacked soil（土tǔ）in his five elements, so his father called him Runtu（闰土）.
>
> ……闰月生的，五行缺土，所以他的父亲叫他闰土。