# Can anyone reccomend me a Chinese female first name?

Tags: names

I want to choose a Chinese name for myself, but I really have no idea how to choose a name that won't be weird.
Here is some information that might be helpful: I am a female and I chose 范 as my surname.
My preference is names that are nature themed, but any other good sounding names will be great too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_given_name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_name These two websites are a little helpful.

Comment: Any reason why "Light" is your moniker? Perhaps someone could suggest something along those lines?

Comment: @T-Pioneer Will check these out, thank you!

Comment: @WayneCheah Light is the meaning of my original given name, but I didn't want to limit myself by trying to find a specific name.

Comment: As a general discussion on names and naming, have a look at this:- https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35844/how-can-i-make-a-two-character-chinese-girls-name-perhaps-using-%e9%9d%99/35856#35856

Comment: @WayneCheah Very informative, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

明珠，菲菲，晴晴，婷婷，婉婉，青青 are names I like.

I know a girl called： 冰凌：icicle

I knew a girl whose 名 was 一， 杨一

珍珍 is also sweet, doubly precious!

仙莹：immortal sparkle

春妮: girl born in spring

煜: glorious, brilliant

如玉: like jade

Chinese names are much more interesting than European names!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of common nature-themed given names for females. The listed names are all for females if not further explained.

Flower-related: 芳，英，荣，华，芬，莉，萍，梅

Tree-related (mostly unisex): 楠，梓，桐，竹

Weather-related：雪 (often 瑞雪)，晴

Water-related (female are often referred by waters): 溪，汀

---

In choosing a name, my suggested formula is

`surname + Characteristic + noun` or `surname + noun`

The surname can be one similar to your original surname or from a historical or legendary person you admire.

The characteristic is some virtue that you value. Examples for females are，淑，慧，睿，婉，丽，婷，俊

The noun is an object that can represent you, maybe a nature-related object in your case.

For example:

```
范淑芬 fan + kind and gentle + flower

范丽华 fan + beautiful + flower

范晴 fan + good weather

范瑞雪 fan + lucky + snow
```

This formula can be used when one has almost no idea of what a regular name should be like. However, there are not many limitations to name choosing. If you have a better idea, you can ignore this formula.

Comment: In my humble opinion, 范淑芬 and 范丽华 are too common and old. I usually see it as a 60-year-old woman's name.

Comment: @T-Pioneer Yes you are right when saying they are super common through ages. Well that also means they are safe to be regular names. If you have a better idea, there is no reason to not go for it.

Comment: My personal favorite are the tree names such as 桐 and 楠, which are not that common but regular.

Comment: @T-Pioneer Is that so? I'm not old so I prefer more modern names, I won't choose these then.

Comment: @River Can I use characteristics with 桐 and 楠 too, or would it sound weird?

Comment: @Light Yes you can.