Is 李飞 a reasonable name in Chinese?
I came across 李飞 a while ago and really like the idea of it at a name, but I'm not entirely confident as to whether it would pass as a 'good name' (i.e. be recognisable as a name and not seem overly strange) and as to what connotations/meanings the name might have.

Sounds OK, not strange at all.

李飞 reminds people of a Martial arts novel titled 小李飛刀. But it is not too strange a name

This is a very common name....

You could get some idea about naming names in a Chinese socio-cultural context in this Post -- https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35844/how-can-i-make-a-two-character-chinese-girls-name-perhaps-using-%e9%9d%99/35856#35856

Rome & Juliet, Act 2 Scene 2 “What’s in a name? That which we call a rose
By any other name would smell as sweet.”

There are all sorts of strange Chinese names, so pretty much anything you pick blends in well.

Sounds reasonable to these 138k 李飞s :)


Question:- "...I'm not entirely confident as to whether it would pass as a 'good name...."
You could get some idea about naming names in a Chinese socio-cultural context in the old Post suggested in my comment.
So, to answer the question whether 李飞 is a "good name" would depend on many factors. Of course it could be that the only thing that matters to you is that you like it or like the sound of it, which is perfectly legitimate.
However, whether it is "good" or not, is an entirely different question, encompassing astrology, numerology, 风水, (Feng Shui), family circumstances, etc, which to many people is just so much mumbo jumbo.
From your question, I think you are more concerned about it being, inadvertently, "offensive", "derogatory", etc.
Well, 李飞 on its own is perfectly Ok, and even common, as a name for a male. It has the overt "aspiration" of bringing greater "heights" to the  李, (a surname), family, as 飞 is to "fly", to "soar", "attainment" to greater heights.
