Assistance Creating Chinese Name
I wanted to see if I could get some help picking out a my name since I'm at day 1 of learning Chinese. I really wanted to stick to what it sounds phonetically and came up with as my given name 布兰地霖, and as my surname 忒漓.
Is it weird? Is is feminine enough for a woman? Should I go back to the drawing board? Any help and suggestions is much appreciated!

Just some general considerations when the Chinese chose names in the old days. It goes beyond just sounding nice. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35844/how-can-i-make-a-two-character-chinese-girls-name-perhaps-using-%e9%9d%99/35856#35856

布兰冬琳 特里 简称 特丽女士 布琳女士 冬琳

You might try to find one of these : https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%B8%B8%E8%A7%81%E5%A7%93%E6%B0%8F%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8  , look like 忒漓 sound close to  林 or 李

There's much foreigner lady named 布蘭妮.李 , it's more feminine.  or 布蘭達.林 . FYR

Y'all are learning languages saviors! Thank you so much for the suggestions!!

With a name like Brandonlyn I'm guessing you are American. The surname Terry identifies you as the heiress apparent to Terry's Chocolate Empire.
The B suggests using 白, snowy, white pure. But that is a surname in China.
So now you are 白兰琳: White Orchidgem
Happy New Year, 白兰琳女士！

Happy New Year! You're a life saver! Thank you for blessing my Chinese learning path with such amazing suggestions!
